# Cannot get navbar to function on collapse using react-bootstrap

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm using react-bootstrap to create a responsive navbar and for some reason it will not work. I've tried using react-router-dom to handle page change and creating a function withing the navbar to handle page change to see if that was the issue. The hamburger icon is not even rendering just a gray blank square.

This is my current code

And here is what it renders
[image: Nav]

What else can I try?

```
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container';
import Nav from 'react-bootstrap/Nav';
import Navbar from 'react-bootstrap/Navbar'
import '../css/Navbar.css'

export default function NavbarRender({ currentPage, handlePageChange }){
    return(
        <Navbar collapseOnSelect expand='sm' id='total-nav'>
            <Container>
                <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="responsive-navbar-nav"/>
                <Navbar.Collapse id="responsive-navbar-nav">
                    <Nav className="me-auto">
                        <Nav.Link href="#about" onClick={() => handlePageChange('About')}
                        className={currentPage === 'About' ? 'nav-link active' : 'nav-link'} id="navbar">
                            About
                        </Nav.Link>
                        <Nav.Link href="#portfolio" onClick={() => handlePageChange('Portfolio')}
                        className={currentPage === 'Portfolio' ? 'nav-link active' : 'nav-link'} id="navbar">
                            Portfolio
                        </Nav.Link>
                        <Nav.Link href="#resume" onClick={() => handlePageChange('Resume')}
                        className={currentPage === 'Resume' ? 'nav-link active' : 'nav-link'} id="navbar">
                            Resume
                        </Nav.Link>
                    </Nav>
                </Navbar.Collapse>
            </Container>
        </Navbar>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have that problem when forget to import react-boostrap CSS

```
{/* The following line can be included in your src/index.js or App.js file*/}

import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

Comment: That was it, saved me hours of restructuring thank you!